# C++ Windows Forms Operating System Message capture

Tags: c++, windows, winforms

I have a c++ windows form that can capture messages that are sent within the application using the following code:

```
protected:
virtual void WndProc(Message% m) override 
{
switch (m.Msg)
{
    case WM_USER:
       MessageBox::Show("Encountered WM_USER message");
       break;

    case WM_DESTROY:
       MessageBox::Show("Closing application..");
       break;

    default:
       break;
}
__super::WndProc(m);
}
```

This correctly fires when a WM_USER message or WM_DESTROY message is sent in the application, but does not capture the messages when sent from other applications. I need to be able to access messages that are not explicitly meant for the window in the application.

The form is created and executed using 
    Application::Run(gcnew Form1()); 
which also starts the message loop.

Is it possible to access operating system messages in this method of using C++ and Windows Forms?

Answer (score 1):

You `WndProc` method will execute whenever a message is processed by your window. If the method is not executing, then the obvious conclusion is that the messages you are hoping to capture are not being sent to your window.

Comment: Indeed. Looks like [UIPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Interface_Privilege_Isolation) at work.

Comment: I understand that, I know the messages I am hoping to capture are not sent specifically to my window. However, is there any method of capturing these messages that are not sent to the window?

Comment: Maybe. You should ask a question about that.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Or perhaps the messages are just sent to a different window

Comment: @David, you're right, I shouldn't have taken that for granted :)

Comment: @David, That's the question that I was trying to ask above :)

Comment: There's no real distinction between what you call "system" messages, and any other message, for the purpose of delivery. If you want to capture messages that are going to other places, you need to know where they are going. I can't tell you the specifics of how to solve your problem without knowing what your problem is. All I'm doing is explaining why `WndProc` isn't executing when you hope it will.

Comment: The messages are going to and from devices by way of another API. I have access to source code of another application which performs what i want to achieve by using TranslateMessage() and DispatchMessage() in a while loop but due to using Forms, I have no real access to the message loop...

Comment: Which I cannot do as these are sent to different recipients all the time. I have started to look into using Hooks, but would you consider this a possible solution to this problem?

Comment: Maybe. Hard to say without details.

Comment: Okay, I'll try to go down the avenue of hooks and see where that takes me. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Rather than proposing hooks as a catch all solution, can't you identify the windows that receive the messages? That's the first step. Gain understanding of the problem before attempting to solve it. Anyway, I think I answered the question you asked.

Comment: As far as I can tell there is no way of identifying the windows that receive the messages, which is why I'm considering the hooks solution.

Comment: OK, well I think all of that is way outside of the scope of the question you asked.